# launching python script process from another script on Ubuntu: how to track status?

Tags: python, system, termination

I launch one Python script out of another one on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance using a command:

```
os.system(call)
```

where `call` has the form

```
"./script2.py arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

I've noticed that from time to time `script2.py` somehow terminates prematurely. I have some logging statements in it but they don't show what's going on. So my questions are:

1. I read that `system()` returns some sort of exit status. What's the best test to distinguish between a normal and abnormal termination? That is, I only want to produce a log message inside the calling script if there is some sort of abnormal termination.
2. Is there any sort of system log where I could try to find traces of terminated processes?

Comment: One possible solution may be using `subprocess` module and reading the output of the child (from `stderr`) also. If the return status is not 0, traces may be found in the output.

Comment: elaborating on earl's comment. Use (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) which is a better way than system, spawn, popen, popen2. It will give you input, outut and error pipes. Which you can read to figure out why the errors are not being writte / where are they going. Moreover, always flush your pipes (in my experience popen had this problem where not flushing pipes lead to some buffers being lost / re-written).

Comment: Do you have any meaningful output to the stdout in your child script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your child script does not use standard output for something and returns non-zero on a crash (this should be default for `python` executable though):

```
import subprocess as sp

try:
    sp.check_output(['python', 'child.py'], stderr=sp.STDOUT)
except sp.CalledProcessError as err:
    print 'Child terminated abnormally with error %d, log:' % err.returncode
    print err.output
```

Comment: Earl, what if `child` does produce stdout?

Answer (score 0):

1> os.system returns the system code if it returns 0 process ran and terminated successfully but if it returns any number then generally it means an error but it depeds on how progam responds to the errors what i mean is if progam returns 1 on success os.system will return 1

for example

```
d = os.system('ls')
print d 
d = os.system(your process)
print d
```

2> python provides syslog module you can try it like

```
>>>import syslog
>>>help(syslog)
```

syslog is a buil-in unix api provided by the os itself

http://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html