# Python process dies on Ubuntu: what does the error code mean and is there a fix?

Tags: python, subprocess, termination

I am running multiple copies of the same python script on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance. Each copy in turn launches the same child Python script using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822480/launching-python-script-process-from-another-script-on-ubuntu-how-to-track-stat)

From time to time some of these child processes die. `subprocess.check_output` throws an exception and returns the error code `-9`. I ran the child process directly from the prompt and after running for some time, the process dies with a not-so-detailed message `Killed`.

Questions:

- What does `-9` mean?
- How can I find out more about what went wrong? Specifically, my suspicion is that it might be caused by the machine getting overloaded by the several copies of the same script running at the same time. At the same time, the specific child process that I ran directly appears to be dying every time it's launched, directly or not, and more or less at the same moment (i.e. after processing more or less the same amount of input data). Python is not producing any error messages.
- Assuming I have no bugs in the Python code, what can I do to try to prevent the crashes?

Comment: You could check system logs if you think it can be related to the operating system. `dmesg` would be a start.

Comment: A negative return code means the process was terminated by a signal. -9 means it was a SIGKILL signal. (See the output of `kill -l`.)

Comment: @Lev: I ran `dmesg -T` and saw the following: `Out of memory: Kill process 26365 (python) score 166 or sacrifice child` and then `Killed process 26365 (python) total-vm:209736kB, anon-rss:100140kB, file-rss:4kB`. So I guess the problem is tat the instance is running our of RAM. That explains why I do not get any Python errors when the process is killed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`check_output()` accumulates output from the subprocess in memory. If the process generates enough output it might be killed by [oom killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) due to the large RAM consumption.

If you don't need the output, you could use `check_call()` instead and discard the output:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, "r+b")

check_call([command], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

-9 means kill signal that is not catchable or ignorable, or just quit immediately.

For example if you're trying to kill a process you could enter in your terminal:

```
ps aux | grep processname
```

or just this to get a list of all processes: `ps aux`

Once you have the pid of the process you want to terminate, you'd type kill -9 followed by the pid:

```
kill -9 1234
```

My memory is a little foggy when it comes to logs, but I'd cat around in /var/log/ and see if you find anything, or dmesg.

As far as preventing crashes in your Python code, have you tried any exception handling?

[Exceptions in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Is this were a python error, I would expect it to produce at least some sort of error message besides `Killed` when the process crashed. But it looks like the problem is RAM of the machine (see my comment above)